# Finite sets and relations with boolean matrix

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm reading about the category $\mathbf{FinRel}$ [on the $n$Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FinRel) and it said: "$\mathbf{FinRel}$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Mat(Bool)}$", without giving any explanation. Does anyone know how to prove it?

Comment: FWIW a wonderful application of this equivalence is https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00061

Comment: @SteveHuntsman Well, a neat application, but there are differences to what this question is about. FinRel and Mat(Bool) are have distinct domain and codomain sides, whereas the boolean arrays of [that paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00061) only have a codomain side (although it can be incident with several objects on that side) — it's the difference between a directed graph and an undirected hypergraph. As a result their wiring diagrams ("generalised matrix multiplications") only become an operad, whereas already FinRel and Mat(Bool) are PROPs.

Comment: Just if you are looking for more references, I believe that the proof of this fact is a slight modification of Proposition 2.6 in one of my go to papers [Some algebraic laws for spans (and their connections with multirelations)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106610480937X), by Bruni and Gadducci which exhibits an equivalence between spans of (infinite) sets and multirelations.

Answer (score 7):

My comment was misleading, and written in haste. Here's a better version. Recall that the objects of $\mathrm{Mat(Bool)}$ are the natural numbers, and a morphism $n\to m$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of [booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_domain), which we can identify with $0,1$. There is an inclusion functor
$$
\mathrm{Mat(Bool)} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{FinRel}
$$
sending $n\mapsto \{1,\ldots,n\} =: \mathbf{n}$, and the matrix $A$ to the subset of $\mathbf{m} \times \mathbf{n}$ whose indicator function is given by $A$, which is interpreted as a function $\mathbf{m} \times \mathbf{n} \to \{0,1\}$. Matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of relations. Every relation from $\mathbf{n}$ to $\mathbf{m}$ can be uniquely reconstructed from such a indicator function/matrix. This means the inclusion is fully faithful. The inclusion is essentially surjective since there is a bijection between a finite set and one of the standard finite sets $\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your proof of functor from MatBool -> FinRel is clear and straight-forward. Although I do have another question: 

in the end you mentioned the inclusion is surjective, to prove equivalence we still need to define the other functor, from FinRel -> MatBool, and prove the adjoint exists, correct? 

Excuse me if the question is juvenile - am a beginner in category theory.

Comment: @GalaxyY this is true, but you can get that from standard theory, see eg Prop 2.2 at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+of+categories (one must choose an isomorphism from each finite set $S$ to $\mathbf{n}$, where $|S|=n$, then the other functor is built algebraically and is an adjoint inverse to the inclusion). Or, to keep it on the SE network, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657707/fully-faithful-and-essentially-surjective-is-an-equivalence